# Android 7'' Tab and 5'' Handset XML layout conflict

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a Android application that will support both 7" Tab and 5" Handset. I have created layout-large-mdpi (drawable-large-mdpi) for 5" Handset and layout-sw600dp for 7" Tab. But i am always getting tablet view in my 5" Handset. Please give me some information.

Comment: Which devices and version of Android are you testing on.

Comment: Samsung note2(Jelly Bean) and Samsung Tab2(Jelly Bean)

Comment: @YajneshwarMandal i'm facing the same problem on my project and i'm not sure that Note2 is a mdpi device but an xhdpi. Retain all your folders and add drawable-large-xhdpi with some dumb-images. Unfortunately i don't have a Note2 and i don't trust at 100% the virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the screen ranges of Android Devices from the below image:

(Source - Andriod Developers Site)

[image: Source - Andriod Developers Site]

So, from the above image, 7" inch and 5" screen devices falls under `hdpi` category.

Please check **"Using configuration qualifiers"** section of [`How to support Multiple Screens`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

Comment: can you please tell me the drawable and Layout folder structure

Comment: I have updated my answer... Please check. You can refer the above image for creating different folder structure using the link provided `How to support Multiple Screens`

Comment: @Avadhani Screen size and density are independent. The original Kindle was 7" tablet with mdpi.

Comment: @AvadhaniY Just saw the update with the link. Devices mentioned by OP are both hdpi. Wasn't sure earlier.

Comment: @YajneshwarMandal do u find the solution??

Comment: @Avadhani Y  nope: till i am facing the same problem. I have created layout-large-mdpi for 5" Handset and layout-sw600dp for 7 " Tab. Can you please tale me in which folder i will create create for 5" Handset and which for 7" Tab.